# Ssis package parallel scheduling

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I am working on a project where I have more than 200 packages, some packages are dependent on each other where as many packages are independent

For example. 
suppose we have 4 packages named: A,B,C & D
where B,C & D is dependent on A but they are not interdependent.

so what we want is when Package A complete its execution all package i.e., B,C & D Start executing.

Currently its executing one by one in serial style.

I want to make it execute in parallel either by any batch script or any other way.

Any lead will be helpful.

Working on mssql 2014, Sql server data tool for vs 2013

Comment: How flexible does it have to be? I've built a tool that allows you to customise what package runs, in what order, and which ones are in parallel. Regardless you still need to create a parent package to run all of these packages

Comment: what kind of tool it is? is it a wrapper package? basically there are some package which is of level 0 types and others are at level 1 that means level 1 are dependent on level 0 but they are not inter dependent. Once all the package of level 0 complete its execution the level 1 packages can start their execution

Comment: Yes a wrapper package with a bunch of 'execute package' tasks in parallel  that is run from the database. Then I have a front end to configure what packages to run, which ones are in parallel, what parameters to run with. So it's simple to piece together all of my packages any way I like

Comment: What I need to create that kind of UI to deploy the package...as I tried to create an execute package task I Need to first import the package in msdb after that I am able to get the package.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper package E, that calls B, C & D as sub-packages, all in parallel (no conditional dependencies).

Your SQL Agent job will call package A, and then package E.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Execute Package Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137609.aspx) from a master package (this will be the package  you will schedule in your SQL Server Agent) and then connect the Execute Package Tasks based on your package dependencies.

For example, create an Execute Package Task for A first, then create a **Sequence Container** containing B, C and D where all 3 packages run in parallel. Finally connect Execute Package Task for A to the sequence container with a **Success** constraint.